# Differential equation $y'=2y-2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the equation $y'=2y-2$

I know the answer should have some form connected to exponentials, but don't know how to work the steps from this form.

Edit: I followed this solution to get $1+e^{2x+2c}$. However, the textbook says the answer is $3e^{2t}+1$. How can this be obtained? I have an initial condition of y(0)=3, if that makes a difference

Comment: Do you know how to solve seperable equations? What about first-order linear equations?

Comment: I have seen some examples of separable equations, but not first order. I'm not very comfortable with any method.

Comment: You can check that answer easily enough.  Just take the derivative.

$y(t)=3e^{2t}+1 \implies \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} (3e^{2t}+1) = 6e^{2t} \implies y'= 3y - 2$.

So either you've copied the question wrong, or the textbook's answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice

$$ \frac{ dy}{dx} = 2(y-1) \iff \frac{dy}{(y-1)} = 2 dx$$

Integrating, we obtain

$$ \int \frac{dy}{y-1} = 2 \int dx $$

Hence, (for arbitrary constants $C, K$):

$$ \ln(y-1) = 2x  + C \iff y-1 = e^{2x}e^C \iff y(x) = 1 + Ke^{2x}$$

From initial conditions: $y(0) = 3 \implies 1 + K e^0 = 3 \implies K = 2$

Hence, $$\boxed{y(x) = 1 + 2e^{2x}}$$

Comment: There might be a constant offset of $1$ between this answer and the question as posed...

Comment: I followed this solution to get $1+e^{2x+2c}$. However, the textbook says the answer is $3e^{2t}+1$. How can this be obtained? I have an initial condition of 4, if that makes a difference

Comment: At $x=t=0$ the equation reduces to $1 + e^{2c} = 4$, i.e. $e^{2c} = 3$, as in your solution.

Comment: Hmm, but is that consistent with the textbook solution? I am sure the textbook must be right because this answer has been mentioned in several places. But I can't seem to get the 3 before the e.

Comment: Mistake in my comment: initial condition is y(0)=3

Comment: fixed it now. Hope it is clear now

Comment: $y'(t)= 2y(t)-2 , y(0)=3 \implies y(t)= 2e^{2t}+1$